# If a cosine wave satisfies Maxwell's equations then how does a sine satisfy the equations as well?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, maxwell-equations, vector-fields

Say the real part of

$$\tilde{\mathbf{E}}(z, t)=\tilde{\mathbf{E}}_{0} e^{i(k z-\omega t)}$$

satisfies all Maxwell's equations. Then how can we say the imaginary part satisfies the equations as well?

Griffiths says in a footnote

> Because the real part of E differs from the imaginary part only in the replacement of sine by cosine, if the former obeys Maxwell's equations, so does the latter.

Comment: Just wait a quarter cycle.

Comment: Use the fact that $e^{iz} = \cos z + i\sin z$ and the fact that $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2} + z) = \cos z$

Comment: Any function of $x \pm ct$ satisfies the wave equation (in your example the frequency, $\omega$, and wave number, $k$, satisfy  $\omega = c k$).

Answer (score 1):

Changing the phase by $\frac \pi 2$ results in $\tilde{\mathbf{E}}(z, t)=\tilde{\mathbf{E}}_{0} e^{i(k z-\omega t)}$ becoming $\tilde{\mathbf{E}}(z, t)=\tilde{\mathbf{E}}_{0} e^{i(k z-\omega t-\frac \pi 2)}$.

However $e^{-i\pi/2}=-i$ so the new solution is $\tilde{\mathbf{E}}(z, t)=-i\,\tilde{\mathbf{E}}_{0} e^{i(k z-\omega t)}$ which is the original solution multiplied by a constant term, $-\,i$.

If you take the real part you now get a sine function.

Comment: Thank you,but how could you change the phase by 90 degrees and still have the same equation as you've done in your first two equations

Comment: @YasirSadiq make $t\to t\pm\frac{\pi}{2\omega}$